# How to segue to the root of navigation controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, segue

I am building a form within an app.
When the user clicks on the button of the last screen4 it should start on screen1 again.
Currently there is a Storyboard reference (red arrow) from storyboard3 to storyboard1. The problem is that within the navigation controller the back button is linked to screen4.

So how is it possible to perform a segue from button in screen4 in storyboard3 to screen1 in storyboard 1 (orange arrow) to start the form again?

[image: setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a separate flow to the rest of your app, you could create a new navigation controller for this flow.

Create a new navigationController with screen 1 as its `rootViewController`. Then set the navigationController as the initialViewController of that storyboard. Now this collection of screens will act as a self contained flow inside your main app. Doing this, you can simply call `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` inside the button on screen 4, to return to the first screen.

Also just FYI,

- The reason the red segue has a back button to 4, is because a storyboard reference creates a new instance of the viewController. You are not returning to number 1 here, you are adding a new copy of screen 1 into the navigation stack.
- I don't know if its just the drawing or not, but having 1 screen per storyboard is a waste. Storyboards were designed to have many screens inside each

Comment: Thank you so much! `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` just helped out. I splitted it into different storyboards because my machine from late 2013 had to work hard to add a simple label onto the canvas.